# Swing application that uses a large amount of data

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, embedded-resource

I have developed a swing application that displays images, so I have a large amount of images (more than 1500), I'm asking what is the best way to add these images to the swing project, is it just inserting the images in a specific package, or is it better to add a zip file containing the images, or ...?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "right" answer here depends on what you plan to do with the images.  If you're using them as icons, you might want to externalize those into a zip file or even a directory structure you ship with the app so they can be swapped out if you ever find the need.  A zip file is pretty easy to access from code, and you can even organize it like a java source / package structure and drop it on the classpath so you can load the images with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("whatever")`.  That has the advantage of not conflating actual source code with resource files like images.

Comment: It should be mentioned that if you decide that they belong with the jar file, adding them to the jar is the same as zipping them, as the jar file format _is_ zip.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Note also that Zip(/Jar) with standard compression does nothing good for most media formats (images, sound, video). In fact, it works no better with 'max compression'.  Best to simply use 'no compression'.  With that in mind, it is often easier to put images and media in one (or perhaps more) Jar that is entirely separate to the Jar(s) containing classes, and that in turn suggests 'different package' for the media since one package cannot be split across multiple *signed* (perhaps not immediately relevant here, but who knows how the app. might change in future?) Jars.